# RSYNC with different directory structures

Tags: rsync, source

I'm trying to accomplish the below with RSYNC but can't quite figure out the syntax.  My source contains a folder for each user, then some subfolders under Logs.  I need to capture everything under the numeric folder with the sync.

```
SOURCE DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:  
/STORAGE/user1/db/Logs/151251/  
/STORAGE/user1/db/Logs/156123/  
/STORAGE/user1/db/Logs/117722/  
/STORAGE/user2/db/Logs/178438/  
/STORAGE/user2/db/Logs/161265/  

PREFERRED DESTINATION DIRECTORY STRUCTURE  
/LOGS/user1/151251/  
/LOGS/user1/156123/  
/LOGS/user1/117722/  
/LOGS/user2/178438/  
/LOGS/user2/161265
```

The command I've tried is:

```
rsync -azvr user@server.com:/STORAGE/*/db/Logs/*/ /LOGS/
```

This succeeds in copying all the files from all the numeric subfolders but I need to create the directory structure above (`/LOGS/user/uniqueid/individual` files).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rsync filters to specify which subpaths you want transferred:

```
rsync -asvr --include '*/' --include 'Logs/***' --exclude '*' user@server.com:/STORAGE/ /LOGS/
```

This will create all the source directories on the destination (but not containing any files). To not do this you need to explicitly include all parent directories:

```
rsync -asvr --include '/STORAGE/' --include '/STORAGE/*/' --include '/STORAGE/*/db/' --include '/STORAGE/*/db/Logs/***' --exclude '*' user@server.com:/STORAGE/ /LOGS/
```

**Edit:** To exclude files with a certain extension, add an `--exclude` pattern at the front:

```
rsync -asvr --exclude '*.bdb' --include ...
```

Comment: Thank you!  But will this create the directory structure on the destination server?

Comment: @Jason Yup.​​​​

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried that and there are no files found for sync...?  I also tried `--include '*/db/Logs/***'` and that didn't seem to do the trick either?

Comment: @Jason Ah, the parent directories need to be explicitly included. See my edit for two options.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  I'm a bit closer but still not quite there.  The command is now syncing the files but it's transferring the source directory structure.  So on the destination end, I'm ending up with /LOGS/user1/db/Logs/151251, etc.  Any way I can have it transfer to the destination so that it eliminates the db and Logs folders and puts the numeric folders directly under the user folder (/LOGS/user1/151251, etc.)?  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jason I don't think rsync can do that. You either have to move them afterwards, or sync them individually.

Comment: OK - thanks!  I can live with the duplicate directory structure.  The last thing I'm struggling with is that the Logs folder contains a few files that have a *.bdb extension.  I don't want to copy those files so I've created an `--exclude "*.bdb"` but it's still copying them anyway.  Am I missing something obvious?  :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason See edit.